# Como verificar apropriadamente a existência de um usuário numa RestFul API (Nodejs) enviando Login e Password num verbo GET?

Tags: node.js, api, restful

Verificar a existência de um usuário através numa API RestFul seria uma transação GET dado que seria somente uma select.

Resumidamente estaria enviando o Login e o Password dessa maneira:

```
const validator =require('validator');
app.get('/users/:login/:passwd',function(req,res){
    var login =  validator.trim(validator.escape(req.param('login')));
    var passwd = validator.trim(validator.escape(req.param('passwd')));
    con.query("SELECT * FROM users where login = '"+login+"' AND password='"+passwd+"' ", function (err, result) {
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      else{
            res.json({ result });
      }
    });        
});
```

A minha pergunta se refere ao fato de GET estar enviando informações sensíveis como logim e senha.

Como fazemos essa verificação sem ferir os padrões de boas práticas de Restful API (verbos adequado às transações CRUD) e mantendo a segurança (Não enviar info sensíveis com GET)?

Comment: Deixando de lado o fato dessa sua query ser vulnerável a SQL Injection, já pensou em usar POST ao invés de GET?

Comment: Sim eu sempre usei post. o fato é q estou tentando seguir o standard de restful api, onde toda select é um get. post é apenas para insert.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "todo select é um GET"? Não vamos confundir select de banco de dados(query) com padrões rest de verbos http, até porque posso ter um cadastro(POST) que precisa de uma validação prévia(select no banco). Aparentemente, no seu exemplo, você está fazendo uma autenticação, e autenticação já é outra história, falariamos de OAuth2, Basic Auth, Hmac e etc. Fora que, esse seu path '/users/:login/:passwd' já está fora do "standard" também. Só pensar o seguinte, faz algum sentido alguém inventar um "padrão" onde senhas são enviadas na url?

Comment: Depende da interpretação. Segundo os standards da W3C - veja nesse link https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html as requisições get devem ser usadas para recuperar informação. Essa é a abordagem usada em alguns standards de Restful API. Veja por exemplo esse standard de API da casa branca para documentos oficiais do governo dos EUA https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards . CRUD op - READ => GET => SELECT.  Foi isso que quis dizer com todo GET ser um select ou vice versa

Comment: A minha pergunta tbm não se relaciona com a seguraça. Isso é uma outra estória. Esse código foi usado para teste.

Comment: Sim, requisições get devem ser usadas para recuperar informações. Acho que ficou um pouco confuso pra entender o que realmente você quer fazer. Você quer autenticar um usuário(login) ou apenas verificar se um determinado usuário existe? Dificilmente você vai encontrar alguém falando sobre envio de senhas na url (GET), até porque qualquer sniffer conseguiria capturar os dados mesmo usando ssl.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67287/discussion-between-tom-melo-and-zwitterion).